# Flask email link prefixed with link

Tags: python, flask, flask-mail

I have a Flask backend. I'm sending a registration link to users. The link that arrives in the email (I'm sending it to my personal hotmail email address) is as follows:

```
[staging.site.com/#/sign-up/MQ.Xz3qZQ.bPIbKHLD_M9XkFZv2lZcHDabIs4]staging.site.com/#/sign-up/MQ.Xz3qZQ.bPIbKHLD_M9XkFZv2lZcHDabIs4
```

My template is as follows:

```
<p>Welcome! You've been invited to register on xxx. Please follow this link to create your account:</p>
<p><a href="{{ confirm_url }}">{{ confirm_url }}</a></p>
<br>
<p>Cheers!</p>
```

And I'm passing it as a hardcoded url to the template:

```
confirm_url = 'staging.site.com' + '/#/sign-up/' +  str(token)
template = render_template('activate.html', confirm_url=confirm_url)
```

Here's an image of the email that I receive:
[image]

However, the curious thing is that on the MacOS Mail client, the link appears normally like so, but clicking the link doesn't do anything:
[image]

Any insight about how to resolve the url appearance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

you can use

```
{{ url_for('name of function', token = token, _external=True) }}
```

instead of

```
{{ confirm_url }}
```

Checkout the highlighted paragraph of [this](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-x-email-support#:%7E:text=next%20section.%20The-,_external%3DTrue,-argument%20that%20I) tutorial